# Why does feedly not load for me in Chrome Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome

(It used to work fine!)

Whenever I try to access http://cloud.feedly.com/ or http://cloud.feedly.com/#latest, I get a white screen.

What I have tried:

- Clearing my cache.
- Checking the console for errors (none).
- Checking the network tab, the AJAX request doesn't get executed.
- Restarting my browser.
- Restarting the PC.

It works well on Firefox.

What can be the problem? What more can I try to do?

Comment: Since this is obviously a browser issue, this would probably be better off at [su]. That said, have you tried with all your extensions disabled?

Comment: @AlEverett: I haven't. Worth a shot.

Comment: @AlEverett: Turns out it was a problem with a Chrome extension. I flagged this question to be migrated to [su], thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was eventually a problem with one of the extensions I installed.

After checking the site without extensions enabled, and enabling them one-by-one, like the comment suggested, I was able to view the site again.